# GMap V3 Multi Criteria Check Box Filtering

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, checkbox, filtering

Been working on this for a week and could do with some guidance:

Need to use two columns of check boxes to filter markers on map.
 Column 1 is: data.ConType
 Column 2 is: data.Operator

I need it to check the tick box and return only the markers that match the criteria of both columns of ticked boxes.

I have got it working on the 1st column and have tried using the && function to have it read the second and match but so far it does not work.
Here is the working section of the show function:

```
// === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
      marker.mycategory = data.ConType;
      marker.myname = data.Name;
      marker.myoperator = data.Operator,
      gmarkers.push(marker);
      // end Looping through the JSON data
      <!-- Map traffic begin -->
      (function (marker, data) {
          // Attaching a click event to the current marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {}); // end Attaching a click event to the current marker
          })(marker, data); // end Creating a closure

      }
} // end of initialize function

// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category) {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }
  // == check the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
}

// == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
function hide(category) {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
  // == clear the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
  // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
  infoBubble.close();
}

// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
function boxclick(box,category) {
  if (box.checked) {
    show(category);
  } else {
    hide(category);
  }
  // == rebuild the side bar
  makeSidebar();
}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
}
```

Has anyone got any pointers or a working webpage/jsfiddle/GitHub with this sort of working criteria?